# Python __repr__ method: writing a JS equivalent?

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, singly-linked-list

I am working through a short beginner's course on Algorithms and Data Structures. The instructor's language is Python; I am converting the code examples to JavasScript. So far, so good.

I am dealing with Linked Lists. The instructor tests the code using Python's  `__repr__()` method. After days of trial and error, I have a working JS solution, but it is not exactly the same as the Python code. I would like to know if there is a better way of implementing the JS code, which I provide, along with the Python code.

**Python**

```py
# class LinkedList and its methods are presumed to exist

def __repr__(self):
  
  nodes = []
  current = self.head

  while current:
    if current is self.head:
      nodes.append("[Head: %s]" % current.data)
    elif current.next_node is None:
      nodes.append("[Tail: %s]" % current.data)
    else
      nodes.append("[%s]" % current.data)

    current = current.next_node
  return '-> '.join(nodes)

# running script
>>> l = LinkedList()
>>> l.add(1)
>>> l.add(2)
>>> l.add(3)
>>> l
[Head: 3]-> [2]-> [Tail: 1]  # output
>>>
```

**JS**

```js
// class LinkedList and its methods are presumed to exist

repr () {
  
  let nodes = "";
  let current = this.head;

  while (current) {
    if (current === this.head) {
      nodes = `Head: ${current.data}-> `;
    } else if (current.nextNode === null) {
      nodes += `Tail: ${current.data}`;
    } else {
      nodes += `${current.data}-> `;
    }
    current = current.nextNode;
  }
  return nodes;

// running the script
let l = LinkedList();
l.add(1);
l.add(2);
l.add(3);

let result = l.repr();
console.log(result);  // Head: 3-> 2-> Tail: 1
```

Again, the two fragments will only run in a full implementation of the Linked List algorithm, but they do work.

Attempts I have made: I tried to use JS `toString()`, `append()` and `appendChild()`, but they were too difficult for me to understand how best to use them, particularly as the last two modify the DOM. I'm sure there is a better way of implementing a JS equivalent of the Python `__repr__()`; I would like to know how it might be done.

Comment: That looks quite reasonable to me. Couple nitpicks: always define variables before using them (use `const` and `let`), and `nodes` should be initialized to an empty string, not an array, but I don't see any notable structural improvements to be made

Comment: @CertainPerformance: thank you for your vote of approval. Regarding definitions; an oversight (easily done when working between Py and JS, I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closer implementation would use a `toString` method. This method is called implicitly when a conversion to string is needed. Python has actually two methods for this, which have a slightly different purpose: `__repr__` and `__str__`. There is no such distinction in JavaScript.

Furthermore, we should realise that Python's `print` will implicitly call `__repr__`, which is not how `console.log` works. So with `console.log` you'd have to enforce that conversion to string.

Here is how the given Python code would be translated most literally (I add the classes needed to run the script):

```js
class Node {
    constructor(data, next=null) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next_node = next;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
    }
    add(data) {
        this.head = new Node(data, this.head);
    }
    toString() {
        let nodes = [];
        let current = this.head;
        while (current) {
            if (current === this.head) {
                nodes.push(`[Head: ${current.data}]`);
            } else if (current.next_node === null) {
                nodes.push(`[Tail: ${current.data}]`);
            } else {
                nodes.push(`[${current.data}]`);
            }
            current = current.next_node;
        }
        return nodes.join('-> ');
    }
}

// running script
let l = new LinkedList();
l.add(1);
l.add(2);
l.add(3);
// Force conversion to string
console.log(`${l}`); // [Head: 3]-> [2]-> [Tail: 1]
```

Personally, I would make the following changes (not reflected in the Python version):

- Produce output without the words "Head" and "Tail" and other "decoration". This is too verbose to my liking. Just output the separated values.
- Make list instances iterable, implementing the [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) method (In Python: `__iter__`). Then use this for implementing the `toString` method.
- Allow the list constructor to take any number of values with which the list should be populated.

This leads to the following version:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(data, next=null) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor(...values) { // Accept any number of values
        this.head = null;
        // Populate in reverse order
        for (let data of values.reverse()) this.add(data);
    }
    add(data) {
        this.head = new Node(data, this.head);
    }
    // Make lists iterable
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        let current = this.head;
        while (current) {
            yield current.data;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    toString() {
        // Array.from triggers the above method
        return Array.from(this).join("→");
    }
}

// Provide the desired values immediately:
let l = new LinkedList(3, 2, 1);
console.log(`${l}`); // 3→2→1
```

Comment: trincot: thank you for the examples. Your first example, utilising the ```toString()``` and ```join()``` methods, was what I had wanted to complete, but similar examples on the forum were way too complex for me to understand. Your second example's style is one I will have to familiarise myself with, as I am new to JavaScript and programming in general, so it all seems very mysterious. The reason for the *Head* and *Tail* is to show a beginner, like myself, how a Linked List functions; I appreciate the **reversal** and the immediacy of inputting data. Thank you.

Comment: trincot: are you actually using the JS ```toString()``` method, or is it the name you've given to the **LinkedList** class method? Curious to know. Thanks.

Comment: When JS needs to convert an object to string (like when it is used in a template literal), it will check whether that object has (or inherits) a `toString` method. If so, it will be called. So because we have defined a `toString` method on the prototype (class), it will be called. If we wouldn't have defined it, JS would have found `Object.prototype.toString` (predefined in JS) and would have executed that instead.

Comment: trincot: I see. This would also explain the use of other **Object.Prototypes** on a class method, such as ```push``` and  ```pop```. I did find It a little confusing why the names of the JS methods were being used and whether there was a conflict in doing so; for this reason, I opted to create original method names. It may have added an extra step in calling the method, but it made sense to me to implement my class methods this way.

Comment: True, but the same argument could be made for Python's `__repr__`. Just like Python calls `__repr__` *implicitly* when it is implemented, so also `toString` is called much in the same way (although JS and Python differ somewhat in how inheritance is provided). I didn't quite follow what you meant with `push` and `pop`: those are native methods on the `Array` prototype (not `Object`prototype), and they are never called implicitly.

Comment: trincot: with regard to Python: its ```append``` method was employed in the implementation of the Linked List that I am converting. I wanted to do something similar, so my search brought me to a few posts elsewhere, where the JS equivalents were utilised in much the same way. With regard to the confusion around ```Array``` and ```Object``` prototypes: I am very new to this game and still learning the rules.

Comment: Indeed: Python's `append` method for `list` instances translates to JS's `push` method for `Array` instances.